# system will poweroff automatically in Lenovo ideapad Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, ubuntu-drivers

I've a new Lenovo Ideapad 330 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed, the System will automatically turned off while working without any specific alerts.
Is there any possible way to turn the power notification on while battery is low.

Comment: There is a low power notification. In your case it maybe overheating.

Comment: I dont think so, Since we have 4 laptops with same configuration and all the four have the same issue.

Comment: What is the "same" configuration? Does it have discrete graphics?

Comment: What does `/var/log/dmesg` and/or  `/var/log/messages` say around the shutsown-time ?

Comment: My shutdown info :  **shutdown system down  4.18.0-15-generi Tue Feb 26 14:36 - 14:36  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-15-generi Tue Feb 26 09:52 - 09:52  (00:00)**